# What are some good books on history of mathematical thought?

Tags: mathematics

And if possible books that could be downloaded for free

Comment: Is "mathematical thought" something different from "mathematics"?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are you referring to mathematical history (as in [this](https://www.amazon.it/Mathematical-Thought-Ancient-Modern-Times/dp/0195061357) classic) or are you referring to something more specific to the history of logic?

Comment: This question is too broad for this site. Type "history of mathematical thought" into Google's search box, select Books, and read the reviews. "Good" depends on what you are looking for.